# AWS SDK: How to get the response body for a 404

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-php-sdk

I'm attempting to access a remote GraphQL server used by a publicly available web site.  I've pieced together the appropriate code to interact with the database and can run it locally successfully.  It involves me getting some `createCognitoIdentity()` credentials and then using those credentials to send a GraphQL query.  Works like a charm and I get the data I'm looking for... until deployed to prod.

Once in prod, the same code produces a 404 error and I'm unable to even try to query the db because getting the credentials fails with:

Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata service. (Client error: `GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://ww (truncated...) )

Here's my code to recreate it:

```
$sdk = (new \Aws\Sdk([
    'region' => 'us-east-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
]));
$result = $sdk->createCognitoIdentity()->getCredentialsForIdentity([
    'IdentityId' => 'us-east-2:3945b61f-5ad6-4e57-b7bf-2d01874e94d4',
]);
```

My production environment is hosted within AWS, so I suspect it's possible the 404 is because it's within AWS?  Seems strange to add such a restriction.  I'd like to rule out any potential xml present within the response body, but I'm having trouble obtaining the full body.

**How can I echo out the response body when a 404 is encountered?**

Comment: Bit confused about Q. "(truncated...)" is part of the client library output and you want the client library to not truncate?

Comment: Yes, that's what I think is the next troubleshooting step, however if someone happens to know why this is showing a `404` that would be great as well :)

Comment: OK. Well, what comes to mind is you need to ensure that API (169.254.169.254) is enabled on the given box. I don't think it's just always there.

Comment: @spinkus I'm trying to obtain credentials for a resource outside of my VPC.  This is on a web site that's publicly accessible, it's essentially what the browser does when I visit their site in order to query data to be displayed on the page.  I'm trying to use their GraphQL database as an API to their data by authenticating and performing a query.  I can auth and run the query from my local machine, but not from my docker container running on an EC2 node in my own VPC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is that there are no IAM credentials associated with the EC2.  I have an EC2 that has an IAM role tied to it.  To check this I run:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

On the instances with an IAM role attached I get the role name that is attached - nothing but the name (i.e. no HTML or anything else).  On another instance that has no credentials and running the same command I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
  <title>404 - Not Found</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>404 - Not Found</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

which looks like what you're getting.  This is from the command line but `cURL` should get you almost the exact same thing in PHP.

**Edit based on the comments**

It sounds like the challenge is ultimately that your development environment has credentials set but your EC2 doesn't.  The error is a bit misleading as it's ultimately a permission denied (as there are no credentials) but it's surfaced as a 404 because there isn't anything in the metadata.

There is more information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) regarding the use of instance profiles.  As you're using a Docker to deploy and based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35495028/docker-containers-seem-to-inherit-the-instance-profile-of-the-host-ec2-how) the container should be able to get the same profile as if you were running natively.

Comment: This works fine when I run it locally, so are you suggesting in order to access this remote resource (not in my VPC) I need to add an IAM role to the instances where my docker container is running?  I don't have a good understanding TBH of why IAM credentials would be tied to an instance to begin with.

Comment: @Ben - I'm not following the "remote resource".  The [EC2 metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html) is attached to every EC2 and is only accessible from that machine.  The 169.254 address space is private and non-routable meaning that you can't access it from anywhere except the machine you're on.  The *address* is the same across machines but the data is for that machine only.  IAM roles are tied to an EC2 to give anything running on that machine the same permissions without having, for example, a local `~/.aws/credentials` file.

Comment: "Remote resource" means the auth process is to enable me to connect to the publicly available GraphQL resource at `ow6vrwzh7fdp3m5ugnjlaizazm.appsync-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` which is hosted on someone else's VPC.  when I run this AWS code on my macbook, I don't see the 404 and everything works fine.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it now.  In your local environment you must be getting the credentials locally - either from a file or an environment variable.  You need those credentials to do the `getCredentialsForIdentity()` call.  On an EC2 it tries the file and environment variable path too but it also tries instance credentials - the 169.254 address.  As you're not showing an explicit credential provider it goes through the defaults.  You can control this though - see [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_provider.html) for details on doing that.

Comment: :facepalm:, yes I have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and such defined in an .env file for my application which is definitely available at runtime.  It sounds like you're suggesting if I make some creds for an IAM service account available in prod, this would probably start working?

Comment: Yes - there are multiple ways to do that but your original question related to accessing them from the EC2 metadata.  To me that's the best setup as your credentials are not store in code or a file but rather "in" the EC2.  You should be able to access the 169.254 address from a container too based on what I'm reading. You'll need to create that role in the IAM side with the credentials you already have and in the EC2 console you "modify the IAM role".

Comment: You're 100% correct, adding the AWS env vars resolved this 404 issue and things are working as expected.  Thank you so much for pairing with m e on this.